# Can we use "with" instead of "by" after passive voice?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Can we use "with" instead of "by" after passive voice?

For instance:
1- It can be done **by** you >>> It can be done **with** you.
2- I was asked **by** him to come here >>>> I was asked **with** him to come here.
3- Our city got cleaned **by** people >>> Our city got cleaned **with** people.

Answer (score 1):

This is a context where preposition usage [has changed over time...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by%20your%20help%2Cwith%20your%20help%2C%28%28by%20your%20aid%29%20*%204%29%2C%28%28with%20your%20aid%29*4%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20your%20help%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20your%20help%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28by%20your%20aid%29%20%2A%204%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28with%20your%20aid%29%20%2A%204%29%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

(I multiplied the ***aid*** values by 4 so one chart shows the same preference shift for both words at once.)

---

It's a risky business assigning precise and consistent *meanings* to English prepositions. In the *specific* context of linking a "result" (or *method* of achieving a result) to some relevant factor, ***by*** and ***with*** (plus ***through*** and possibly others) are "close enough". It's just that ***with*** is currently much more common for the exact context.

So you should note that the actual choice of preposition for OP isn't really a matter of *semantics* or *grammar* - it's just ***idiomatically established preference*** (which may slowly change). By further implication, although there will be some discernible patterns, the inconvenient truth is many of these idiomatically established usages simply have to be learned by rote (but not *...learned **with** rote!* :). Just don't fall into the trap of assuming there's only one "correct" preposition for any given context (*sometimes* that's true, but often not).

---

Note that the specific fact of being "passive" doesn't affect OP's choice of preposition - exactly the same choice applies with all permutations of...

> 1: *It was done [by / with / through] your [aid / help / assistance]*
>    2: *I did it [by / with / through] your [aid / help / assistance]*

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is not grammatical. Things cannot be **done by aid** although they might be done **by aiding somebody**.

Your options are to write either:

> It can be done with your aid
>   or
>   It can be done by you.

The first sentence is more likely than the second; nearly all English speakers would use the active voice: **You can do it**.

Comment: "X done by aid" is grammatical, but the situations where you'd say "X is done by aid" and really want to mean that would be rare.

Answer (score 0):

> It can be done by the aid of you.

This sentence is weird and doesn't work well with passive voice unless you really mean "The aid of you" is the only thing that does "it".

You probably don't mean this--it's not just "the aid of you" that is doing anything.  You more likely mean "the aid of you" plus some other things (the people/etc. needing aid), and all those things together can do "it".

So that's why you'd use *with*.  *By* is a "replacement", *with* is an "addition".